# What are rendering differences between latest versions of Safari(windows) vs Safari(MAc) vs Google Chrome(Mac) vs Google Chrome(Windows)?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

Should i check in all? or in any one is enough because all share same rendering engine Webkit.

My question is related to HTML CSS rendering.

I know one difference Safari for windows and MAC both have Font smoothing (anti -alisaing)

Is there any other differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's definitely a difference between Chrome and Safari due to Safari's font rendering. In Safari text tend to be a bit bolder due to the anti-aliasing algorithm and can sometimes take up a few extra pixels on the screen.

Also keep in mind that Safari uses the SquirrelFish javascript engine while Chrome uses V8.

Comment: difference of javascript engine can make any differences in html css presentation?

Comment: If your page doesn't use javascript at all then you don't need to worry. It's not the html or css that might break, it's the javascript code.

Comment: so no need to worry about if javascript engine is different, if  engine is different then i think it's a matter of javascript rendering speed not HTML css rendering

Comment: I use jquery which is cross browser compatible. would i get any type of problem because Safari uses the SquirrelFish javascript engine while Chrome uses V8?

Comment: If jQuery is really cross browser compatible then we wouldn't be getting questions like `"my jQuery code works in <insert browser> but does not work in <insert IE version>"` once every two weeks (last week alone I counted 3). It's good to use a library because they've solved a lot of cross browser problems for you. But library authors are mere mortals and the best any of us can do is try.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a difference in the way Safari and Chrome select SELECT boxes. I think Chrome seems to ignore line-height whereas in Safari line height seems to make a difference.

Safari Windows 5.1.7 v's Chrome Windows Version 22.0.1229.94 m

I think this is to do with the default user agent style?

Answer (score 1):

I would check, yes.

Whilst the browsers all use the same rendering core, they're not necessarily on the same version (and there are multiple versions of Safari out there in any case).

Also, as slebetman says, font rendering is quite different depending on OS and anti-aliasing settings too, so you need to be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

There are major and minor differences. Do check!

**Minor:** full support for CSS3 border-radius in Chrome. I've read about, but can't find, this in Safari.

**Major:** zooming in Chrome zooms everything. (This is the behavior in almost every browser.) Zooming Safari zooms text but leaves other things unchanged. Your ever-so-carefully-laid-out form is highly likely to be trashed if the user zooms in. Leave lots of extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Shadows are fast&ugly in chome; slower&prettier in safari (and firefox).  IIRC there was some difference in CSS3 transitions too - but really, these details are still in flux anyhow and change from version to version.

In practice, I only check one of the two regularly, which is generally fine.  Before putting major changes online, it's obviously not a bad idea to check *again*, but during development, it's not worth the hassle; they're so similar anyhow...